# Cannot import SOAP service written in PHP in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

I'm trying to import the service with the WSDL located at:
http://rxb.se/dmdstats/server_actionbase.php?WSDL&readable
Into my visual studio 2012 project. But I get errors:

```
Custom tool error: Unable to import WebService/Schema. Unable to import binding 'ActionbaseSoap' from namespace 'http://rxb.se/dmdstats/'. Unable to import operation 'getCampaigns'. The datatype 'http://rxb.se/dmdstats/:intArray' is missing.
```

Can anyone successfully import this? I think it cannot see the definition for array. Is there a way I can get over this or does the error come from the service provider?
I'm using C# by the way.

I have tried both "add service reference" and "add web reference" to no avail.

Comment: You found any answer?

Comment: How did you fixed it? I see that your wsdl is working well now. I have the same problem with some soap service written with php.